# RxJS createEpicMiddleware Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs

I've been looking at this problem for a couple of days now, but as I am not a frontend developer I'm having to throw in the towel.
I'm building a simple web app with react and rxjs - the code is hosted here: https://github.com/themoffster/webapp

My problem is when I try to hook in my epics via createEpicMiddleware (as described here https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html), I'm getting the following error:

```
combineEpics.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at combineEpics(combineEpics(:8082/checkout)) (http://localhost:8082/js/bundle.js:114846:56)
at MapSubscriber.project (createEpicMiddleware.js:28)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
at Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
at Function.epicMiddleware.run (createEpicMiddleware.js:62)
at configureStore (configureStore.js:29)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b320e87a17c200c73310:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:36283)
```

I've dug into it and I am passing my root epic ok as it is defined, but '`merge`' which is an import within the combineEpics.js file isn't defined - and this file comes from the redux-observable package, not my code. I'm not really sure what's going on.

In order to recreate the issue...

1. `git clone` the code
2. `yarn install`
3. `yarn start`
4. the browser will auto launch and with Chrome dev tools on, you'll see the error.

Any pointers welcome.
Cheers

Comment: Can you share relevant code.

Comment: The full code is hosted here: https://github.com/themoffster/webapp but the code which is called that the error propagates from is
https://github.com/themoffster/webapp/blob/master/src/dependencies/store/configureStore.js

Comment: Yes I know, but it's easier if you share the part you think is relevant, it might also be beneficial for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing these dependencies:

```
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
```